# Fermat-like equation $c^n=a^{2n}+a^n b^n + b^{2n}$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,

Is there a solution to the following equation:

$c^n=a^{2n}+a^n b^n + b^{2n}$
where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}^*$, and $n$ is an integer $\geq 2$.

The problem is due to Antoine Balan.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great question.  It is to the set 0,infinity,exp(2pi/3),exp(4pii/3) what Fermat is to (0,infinity,1).  I suppose if I wanted to cook up a natural "Frey curve" in this situation I would try to find a way to express that 4-punctured sphere as some friendly (possibly twisted) moduli space of elliptic curves with some kind of level structure.
 

Comment: I think it is impossible for n=2, since we know that Pythagorean triples are of the form $m^2 - n^2, 2mn, m^2 + n^2$

Comment: Not sure how the impossibility for $n=2$ is supposed to follow from the parametrization of Pythagorean triples as B.Banwait claims.  Still it's true that there are no solutions in positive integers with $n=2$.  The equation is an elliptic curve isomorphic with $y^2 = (x+1)(x^2-4)$.  It has conductor $48$, so we can look it up in tables (or run Cremona's **mwrank**) to find that there are only the four rational points corresponding to trivial solutions with $ab=0$.

Comment: @JSE: Could you make that analogy more precise?

Comment: By [Lander, Parkin, and Selfridge conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lander,_Parkin,_and_Selfridge_conjecture) there is no answer if n>4

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Writing the equation as
$$
c^n+(ab)^n = (a^n+b^n)^2,
$$
one has, via results of Darmon and Merel, and Poonen, that there
are no solutions for $n \geq 4$, provided the three terms are coprime.
If $n=2$, I think Pythagorean triply stuff shown that there are again no
solutions. In the case $n=3$, I guess one could again look at the
parametrizations for $X^3+Y^3=Z^2$, say in Cohen's GTM. I'm not sure how 
hard this case is....

The condition on coprimality might be a problem, but it's too early
in the morning for me to be sure!

Comment: SLICK!

Amusingly enough, the reason I returned to this question was to add a comment saying "You should really ask Mike Bennett."

Comment: Did not Fermat himself effectively take care of the case n=4k?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.09.18

Comment: Hi Jordan! Gerhard is certainly correct about the cases where $4 \mid n$. The $n=3$ case can likely be attacked using Chabauty, but I don't see it immediately -- unless I'm missing something, the obvious genus one covers have positive rank.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it's a nice question.  It does seem that there are no solutions in
positive integers to A. Balan's equation, and indeed no integer
solutions at all other than those with $a=0$, $b=0$, or (when $n$ is
odd) $a+b=0$.  As usual the problem is equivalent to finding all
rational points on an algebraic curve $B_n$; here $B_n$ is the
"superelliptic" curve with affine equation $y^n = x^{2n} + x^n + 1$.
We want to show that the only rational points are those with
$x=\infty$, $x=0$, and (when $n$ is odd) $x=-1$.  Herewith:

1) Verification that $ab$ and $c$ may be assumed coprime; by
M.Bennett's clever rewriting and the results he quotes from DMP =
Darmon, Merel, and Poonen, this reduces the problem to $n=2$ and $n=3$.

2) $n=2$, worked out in more detail than in my comment to the original
question.

3) $n=3$; fortunately a genus-2 quotient $C_3$ of $B_3$ has torsion Jacobian.

4) A bit more on the analogy JSE suggested:
Balan is to $\lbrace0,\infty,\rho,\rho^2 \rbrace$
as Fermat is to $\lbrace 0, 1, \infty \rbrace$
(where $\rho = e^{2\pi i/3}$), and why the proof suggested
by this analogy seems to barely fail.

5) Where Bennett's approach fits in this picture.

**(1)** Mike finished his answer with the sentence "The condition on
coprimality might be a problem, but it's too early in the morning for
me to be sure!"; by now he's probably had the chance to check this, but
I don't see it yet as an edit or a comment, so here goes.  To apply DMP
to $c^n + (ab)^n = (a^n+b^n)^2$ we need $c$ coprime to $ab$.  If $p$
divides $c$ and (say) $a$, then taking the equation mod $p$ yields
$p|b^n$, and then $p|b$, so $p^{2n} | a^{2n} + a^n b^n + b^{2n} = c^n$,
whence $p^2 | c$.  At this point we may replace $(a,b,c)$ by the equivalent
solution $(a/p, b/p, c/p^2)$.  Unless $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$, in finitely
many steps we reach an equivalent solution with $\gcd(ab,c)=1$ as
desired.  If $n\geq 4$, it follows from DMP that at least one of $ab$,
$a^n+b^n$, and $c$ vanishes, and we're done.

It remains to deal with $n < 4$.

**(2)**  $B_2: y^2 = x^4 + x^2 + 1$ is an elliptic curve.  It has
rational points at infinity, so we put it in extended Weierstrass form
by the usual centuries-old technique.  Choose a point $P$ at infinity,
and expand $y$ about $P$ in a Laurent series, truncating before the
constant term to get a quadratic polynomial; here it's just $x^2$.
Hence $t := y+x^2$ has a double pole at $P$ and nowhere else on the curve,
so it can be used as the abscissa.  Writing $y=t-x^2$ in $y^2 = x^4 + x^2 + 1$
gives a quadratic in $x$, namely $(2t+1)x^2 = t^2-1$, which has solutions
iff $4(2t+1)(t^2-1)=u^2$ for some $u$;
dividing $t$ by $2$ yields $(t+1)(t-2)(t+2) = u^2$, which is
the curve of conductor $48$ with coefficient vector $[0,1,0,-4,-4]$.
Thanks to rational $2$-torsion (and trivial Sha[2] obstruction),
Fermat's descent technique, now automated in Cremona's **mwrank**,
suffices to prove the curve has rank zero and no rational points
other than the four trivial ones we already knew of.

**(3)**  $B_3: y^3 = x^6 + x^3 + 1$ has genus $4$.  There's an obvious
quotient curve of genus $1$, namely
$E: Y^{\phantom.3} = X^{\phantom.2} + X + 1$,
which is already in the usual extended Weierstrass form
(with the roles of $X$ and $Y$ reversed).  Unfortunately the
obvious points with $Y=1$ are of infinite order; indeed plugging the
coefficient vector $[0,0,1,0,-1]$ into **mwrank** we find that
$(X,Y\phantom.) = (0,1)$ (or equivalently $(-1,1)$)
generates the group of rational points.  (We could have known in advance
that the rank cannot exceed $1$ because its conductor is $3^5 = 243 < 389$...)
So we cannot use this quotient to prove that $B_3$ has no more rational points.
Fortunately there is a genus-2 quotient $C_3: Y^{\phantom.3} = X^4 + X^3 + X^2$
that does work.  [To get this quotient, first write $B_3$ as
$(x^2 y)^3 = x^{12} + x^9 + x^6$, then take $(X,Y\phantom.) = (x^2 y, x^3)$.]
To put this curve in hyperelliptic form, divide through by $X^2$
to get $z^3 X = X^2 + X + 1$ where $z = Y/X$, then find the discriminant
of this quadratic in $X$ to get $z^6 - 2z^3 - 3 = w^2$.  The three
known points correspond to the Weierstrass point $(z,w) = (-1,0)$
and the two points at infinity, call them $P_\pm$.
The subgroup of the Jacobian $J(C_3)$ represented by degree-zero
divisors supported on these three points is isomorphic with
${\bf Z} / 6 {\bf Z}$: twice the Weierstrass point is equivalent with
$P_+ + P_-$, and $3P_+ \sim 3 P_-$ because the difference is the
divisor of $z^3 - 1 - w$.  [An analogous result holds for all odd $n$,
but the next step might not.]  It turns out that this torsion group
is all of $(J(B_1))({\bf Q})$: I asked **magma**

```
_<z> := PolynomialRing(Rationals());
C1 := HyperellipticCurve(z^6 - 2*z^3 - 3);
J := Jacobian(C1);
TorsionSubgroup(J);
RankBound(J);
```

(adapting one of the examples in
http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1375),
and found that the Jacobian $J(C_3)$ has $6$ torsion points and rank zero.
It follows that our list of rational points on $C_3$, and thus
also on $B_3$, is complete.

[The Jacobian of the genus-$4$ curve $B_3$ is isogenous with
$E \times E \times J(C_3)$: in general the Jacobian of a superelliptic
curve of the form $y^m = P(x^m)$ is isogenous with the product of the
Jacobians of the $n$ curves $Y^{\phantom.m} = X^k P(X)$ with $k=0,1,2,\ldots,m$,
and here $k=0$ and $k=1$ both yield $E$, while $k=2$ yields $C_3$.]

**(4)**  Recall the following geometrical description of the Frey curves
associated with a putative point on the Fermat curve $F_p: x^p + y^p = z^p$,
with $p>3$ prime.
The rational function $(x/z)^p$ on $F_p$ realizes $F_p$ as a $\mu_p^2$
cover of ${\bf P}^1$, branched only above $\lbrace 0, 1, \infty \rbrace$.
Use the modular function $\lambda$ to identify ${\bf P}^1$ with
the modular curve ${\rm X}(2)$, whose three cusps are at $\lambda=0,1,\infty$.
The image of a putative Fermat counterexample yields a Frey curve
$E: Y^{\phantom.^2} = X (X \pm x^p) (X \mp y^p)$,
with the sign chosen to make the curve semistable even at $2$
(this is where $p>3$ is needed), and thus modular.
But the cover ${\rm X}(2p) \rightarrow {\rm X}(2)$ of modular curves
has the same ramification points and orders as our map from $F_p$.
Once $E$, and thus the Galois representation on $E[p]$, has been proved modular,
it then follows that this mod-$p$ representation comes from a cuspform
of level $2$, which is impossible because fortunately ${\rm X}_0(2)$
has genus zero.

Now the Balan curve $B_p$ is likewise a $\mu_p^2$ cover of ${\bf P}^1$,
but with four branch points, at $(a/b)^p = 0$, $\infty$, $\rho$, and $\rho^2$.
These don't seem to be the cusps of any modular curve.  But for our purpose
it's enough for some subset to be the cusps, and JSE suggested the only
possibility: twist $\Gamma(2)$ by ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ to
put two of its cusps at $\rho$ and $\rho^2$ and the third at $\infty$
(or equivalently at $0$).  Then the Frey curve becomes
$$
E': Y^{\phantom.2} = X \bigl(X^2 + (a^p+2b^p) X + (a^{2p}+a^pb^p+b^{2p}) \bigr),
$$
with discriminant $-48 a^{2p} (a^{2p}+a^pb^p+b^{2p})^p = -48 a^{2p} c^p$.
So we must deal with reduction at $3$ as well as at $2$.  Now the
good news is that $E'$ is semistable at $3$: while there are coprime
integers $A,B$ such that
$Y^{\phantom.2} = X \bigl(X^2 + (A+2B) X + (A^2+AB+B^2)\bigr)$
has additive reduction at $3$, this can only happen if $A\equiv B \mod 3$,
but then $A^2 + AB + B^2 \equiv 3 \bmod 9$ so it cannot be a $p$-th power.
The bad news is that $E'$ is not in general semistable at $2$,
and even after applying the available symmetries $(a,b) \leftrightarrow (b,a)$
and $(a,b) \leftrightarrow (-a,-b)$ the power of $2$ in the conductor
might be as large $2^3$ $-$ this happens exactly when $a \equiv b \bmod 4$.
In this case, all that we can say is that the Galois representation
on $E'[p]$ is isomorphic to the the $p$-torsion of an elliptic curve
of conductor 24, such as $y^2 = x^3 - x^2 + x$ (it is not entirely
coincidental that this curve is a quadratic twist of the one we
encountered above for exponent $2$).  At this point I'm stuck:
there might be a way to push this argument further or modify it
to finish off the proof, but all I can obtain this way is the
unsatisfying conclusion that in any primitive solution $a \equiv b \bmod 4$
and $E'[p]$ has the same Galois structure as the $p$-torsion of
$y^2 = x^3 - x^2 + x$.  The first condition follows from the computation
that in all other cases $E'[p]$ has conductor dividing $12$ for at least one
of the four equivalent choices of $(a,b)$, and then there's no possible
cuspform because ${\rm X}_0(12)$ is rational.  This condition is peculiar
because the curve $B_n$ has good reduction at 2 (it's the construction of
the auxiliary curve $E'$ introduces problems at this prime).  The
condition on $E'[p]$ seems rather hard to exploit...

**(5)** Fortunately there's another way, which comes down to what
Bennett found: compose the map, call it
$t = (a/b)^p: B_p \rightarrow {\bf P}^1$,
with the map $s: t \mapsto t + 1/t$, giving the quotient map
${\bf P}^1 \rightarrow {\bf P}^1$ under the involution
$t \leftrightarrow 1/t$ that switches $0$ with $\infty$ and
$\rho$ with $\rho^2$.  This map has double points at $s = \pm 2$
(images of the fixed points $t = \pm 1$ of the involution),
and takes $t=0,\infty$ to $s=\infty$ and $t = \rho,\rho^2$
to $s = -1$.  So now, in place of ${\rm X}(2)$ we need a
modular curve with cusps at $s=-1$ and $s=\infty$
and an elliptic point of order $2$ at $s=2$ or $s=-2$
(or possibly both).  The modular curve ${\rm X}_0(2)$,
with two cusps and one elliptic point of order $2$,
does the trick, and if we choose to put the elliptic point
at $s=-2$ then there's no problem with reduction at $3$
(putting it at $s=+2$ *would* cause such a problem because
$2 \equiv -1 \bmod 3$).  This yields the elliptic curve
$E'': Y^2 = X \bigl(X^2 \pm 2(a^p+b^p) X + c^p \bigr)$.
That's still not the end of the game: the smallest
valuation at $2$ of any quadratic twist of $E''$ is $5$,
and the modular curve ${\rm X}_0(2^5)$ has genus $1$,
so there is a modular form of level $2^5$ that must be
dealt with.  Fortunately this form, unlike the one of level $24$,
is CM.  Thus the corresponding Galois representation mod $p$
is well understood, and with some further cleverness and much effort
Darmon and Merel were able to dispose of this final case.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add another line of proving this (and similar problems); the proof is not yet formally complete but the method as such seems helpful for many such problems, so I show my reasoning here:

**[update]** *After rereading my own answer I think now, that that line of attack might be more incomplete for this problem than initially thought; that the holes cannot be simply filled with one or two little more thoughts; so possibly I'll retract the whole approach later. Thanks for the upvotings anyway and apologies for distractions ...* **[/update]**
The original answer went as below:

---

Let us define the following notations

a) *{n,p}* the exponent to which a prime *p* occurs in the primefactorization of some number *n*
b) the iverson-bracket *[n:p]* which evaluates to *1* if *p* divides *n* and to *0* if not

c) $ \small f(a,b,n)=a^n - b^n  $ , the short form for expressions where *a,b* are thought to be constant and *n* is seen as varying
d) $ \small \lambda_p $ the smallest *k>0* such that *p* divides $ \small f(a,b,k) $ ,
e) $ \small w_p $ the exponent, to which *p* occurs in $ \small f(a,b,\lambda_p) $ , formally  $ \small w_p=\{ f(a,b,\lambda_p),p \}   $

We use that definitions to rewrite the analysis of the problem in terms of the Euler-totient-theorem and the concept of the order of cyclic subgroups modulo some primes *p*.
Here the idea is to compare the odd primefactors in the canonical primefactorizations of the lhs and rhs in the conveniently rewritten problem
$$ \small c^n-(ab)^n =^? a^{2n}+b^{2n} =  {a^{4n}- b^{4n} \over a^{2n}- b^{2n} } .     $$
It will be sufficient to compare the odd primefactors $ \small p, q \in \text{odd primes} $ only; so we refer to possible exponents of *2* with some anonymous exponents *s* and *t* only. Then the lhs is with $ \small q \in \text{odd primes} $
$$ \small f(c,ab,n)=2^s \prod q^{ [n:\lambda_q] (w_q+\{n,q\})} $$
and the rhs is with some exponent *t* at the primefactor *2* :
$$ \small a^{2n}+b^{2n}={ a^{4n}-b^{4n} \over a^{2n}-b^{2n} }={f(a,b,4n)\over f(a,b,2n)}  $$
and
$$ \small 
{f(a,b,4n)\over f(a,b,2n)} = 2^t {  \prod p^{ [4n:\lambda_p] (w_p+\{4n,p\})} 
                 \over  
             \prod p^{ [2n:\lambda_p] (w_p+\{ 2n , p \} ) } 
            }
$$
Here for all odd primes *p* we have $ \small \{ 4n , p \} = \{ 2n, p \} = \{ n,p \} $,
$$ \small { f(a,b,4n)\over f(a,b,2n)} = 2^t \prod p^{ ([4n:\lambda_p]- [2n:\lambda_p]) (w_p+\{ n, p \} ) } $$

Conclusion: (updated)
In the rhs we get only that primefactors *p*, whose order divide *4n* **but not** *2n* and - having $ \small n = 2^m \cdot o, o \text{ odd } $ thus must be exactly $ \small 4 \cdot 2^m r $ where *r* is any odd divisor of *n*, while on the lhs we get all primes in the factorization whose order equal any divisor of *n*. But the sets of primes must be equal to allow a solution for the original problem.